# Form not submitting when using jQuery modal within a Laravel app

Tags: php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

So I got a really weird problem going on.

I'm using this modal together with a Laravel app: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/modal-login-with-jquery-effects

I adapt the code with the form ID's I've used in my Laravel app and change the element identifier within the jQuery code. The first few times the modal login forms works like a charm. I can sign in and get directed to the right route (/dashboard). 
Then when I leave the application and test after a few hours, *nothing happens when I submit the login form*.

I thought this could have been me making a silly mistake, so I redid the whole thing, and made a copy. But the same thing happens again, both on the new version and the copy I made of it. It works the first few times, then it doesn't.

I noticed one other thing which have changed, and it's the styling, buttons which used to be Round are now Squared. So I don't know what's going on here.
I think it somehow got to be with the CSS, csrf_token or Auth-helper method within Laravel.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="login-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header" align="center">
                    <img class="img-circle" id="img_logo" src="http://bootsnipp.com/img/logo.jpg">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <!-- Begin # DIV Form -->
                <div id="div-forms">

                    <!-- Begin # Login Form -->
                    <form id="login-form" action="{{ route('signin') }}" method="post">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div id="div-login-msg">
                                <div id="icon-login-msg" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></div>
                                <span id="text-login-msg">Type your username and password.</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('email') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                                <input name="email" id="email" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username (type ERROR for error effect)" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('password') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                                <input name="password" id="password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Login</button>
                                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <button id="login_lost_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Lost Password?</button>
                                <button id="login_register_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Register</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>





                    <!-- End # Login Form -->

                    <!-- Begin | Lost Password Form -->
                    <form id="lost-form" style="display:none;">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div id="div-lost-msg">
                                <div id="icon-lost-msg" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></div>
                                <span id="text-lost-msg">Type your e-mail.</span>
                            </div>
                            <input id="lost_email" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail (type ERROR for error effect)" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Send</button>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <button id="lost_login_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Log In</button>
                                <button id="lost_register_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Register</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <!-- End | Lost Password Form -->

                    <!-- Begin | Register Form -->
                    <form id="register-form" style="display:none;">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div id="div-register-msg">
                                <div id="icon-register-msg" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></div>
                                <span id="text-register-msg">Register an account.</span>
                            </div>
                            <input id="register_username" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username (type ERROR for error effect)" required>
                            <input id="register_email" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail" required>
                            <input id="register_password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Register</button>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <button id="register_login_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Log In</button>
                                <button id="register_lost_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Lost Password?</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <!-- End | Register Form -->

                </div>
                <!-- End # DIV Form -->

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END # MODAL LOGIN -->
```

CSS for modal:

```
.modal-backdrop.in {
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: .8;
}

.modal-content {
    background-color: #ececec;
    border: 1px solid #bdc3c7;
    border-radius: 0px;
    outline: 0;
}

.modal-header {
    min-height: 16.43px;
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
}

.modal-body {
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    text-align: left;
    border-top: 0px;
}

.checkbox {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.btn {
    border-radius: 0px;
}

.btn:focus,
.btn:active:focus,
.btn.active:focus,
.btn.focus,
.btn:active.focus,
.btn.active.focus {
    outline: none;
}

.btn-lg, .btn-group-lg>.btn {
    border-radius: 0px;
}

.btn-link {
    padding: 5px 10px 0px 0px;
    color: #95a5a6;
}

.btn-link:hover, .btn-link:focus {
    color: #2c3e50;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.glyphicon {
    top: 0px;
}

.form-control {
  border-radius: 0px;
}
```

jQuery for modal:

```
$(function() {

    var $formLogin = $('#login-form');
    var $formLost = $('#lost-form');
    var $formRegister = $('#register-form');
    var $divForms = $('#div-forms');
    var $modalAnimateTime = 300;
    var $msgAnimateTime = 150;
    var $msgShowTime = 2000;

    $("form").submit(function () {
        switch(this.id) {
            case "login-form":
                var $lg_username=$('#email').val();
                var $lg_password=$('#password').val();
                if ($lg_username == "ERROR") {
                    msgChange($('#div-login-msg'), $('#icon-login-msg'), $('#text-login-msg'), "error", "glyphicon-remove", "Login error");
                } else {
                    msgChange($('#div-login-msg'), $('#icon-login-msg'), $('#text-login-msg'), "success", "glyphicon-ok", "Login OK");
                }
                return false;
                break;
            case "lost-form":
                var $ls_email=$('#lost_email').val();
                if ($ls_email == "ERROR") {
                    msgChange($('#div-lost-msg'), $('#icon-lost-msg'), $('#text-lost-msg'), "error", "glyphicon-remove", "Send error");
                } else {
                    msgChange($('#div-lost-msg'), $('#icon-lost-msg'), $('#text-lost-msg'), "success", "glyphicon-ok", "Send OK");
                }
                return false;
                break;
            case "register-form":
                var $rg_username=$('#register_username').val();
                var $rg_email=$('#register_email').val();
                var $rg_password=$('#register_password').val();
                if ($rg_username == "ERROR") {
                    msgChange($('#div-register-msg'), $('#icon-register-msg'), $('#text-register-msg'), "error", "glyphicon-remove", "Register error");
                } else {
                    msgChange($('#div-register-msg'), $('#icon-register-msg'), $('#text-register-msg'), "success", "glyphicon-ok", "Register OK");
                }
                return false;
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        return false;
    });

    $('#login_register_btn').click( function () { modalAnimate($formLogin, $formRegister) });
    $('#register_login_btn').click( function () { modalAnimate($formRegister, $formLogin); });
    $('#login_lost_btn').click( function () { modalAnimate($formLogin, $formLost); });
    $('#lost_login_btn').click( function () { modalAnimate($formLost, $formLogin); });
    $('#lost_register_btn').click( function () { modalAnimate($formLost, $formRegister); });
    $('#register_lost_btn').click( function () { modalAnimate($formRegister, $formLost); });

    function modalAnimate ($oldForm, $newForm) {
        var $oldH = $oldForm.height();
        var $newH = $newForm.height();
        $divForms.css("height",$oldH);
        $oldForm.fadeToggle($modalAnimateTime, function(){
            $divForms.animate({height: $newH}, $modalAnimateTime, function(){
                $newForm.fadeToggle($modalAnimateTime);
            });
        });
    }

    function msgFade ($msgId, $msgText) {
        $msgId.fadeOut($msgAnimateTime, function() {
            $(this).text($msgText).fadeIn($msgAnimateTime);
        });
    }

    function msgChange($divTag, $iconTag, $textTag, $divClass, $iconClass, $msgText) {
        var $msgOld = $divTag.text();
        msgFade($textTag, $msgText);
        $divTag.addClass($divClass);
        $iconTag.removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-right");
        $iconTag.addClass($iconClass + " " + $divClass);
        setTimeout(function() {
            msgFade($textTag, $msgOld);
            $divTag.removeClass($divClass);
            $iconTag.addClass("glyphicon-chevron-right");
            $iconTag.removeClass($iconClass + " " + $divClass);
        }, $msgShowTime);
    }
});
```

Laravel route:

```
Route::post('/signin', [
        'uses' => 'UserController@postSignIn', 
        'as' => 'signin' 
    ]);

    Route::get('/dashboard', [
        'uses' => 'PostController@getDashboard',
        'as' => 'dashboard',
        'middleware' => 'auth'
    ]);
```

PostController.php:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Post;
use App\Like;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class PostController extends Controller{

    public function getDashboard(){
        $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get(); // MySQL ORDER BY
        return view('dashboard', ['posts' => $posts]);   
    }
}
```

UserController.php:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class UserController extends Controller{

public function postSignIn(Request $request){

        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        //AUTH fetch a helper function named ATTEMPT imported from use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
        if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['email'], 'password' => $request['password']])){
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }
        return redirect()->back();  
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'm running this on a local server using WAMP. I don't get any errors when I inspect with the developer tools. I'm including jQuery in a master file which I'm fetching using blade.

I'm using Laravel's error-reporting like this:

`@if(count($errors) > 0) 
<ul>
      @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
       <li>{{$error}}</li>
      @endforeach
     </ul>
    
@endif`

Not sure if I'm catching all possible PHP-errors though.